# How to set enter animation to RecyclerView items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I am trying to set enter animation for all RecyclerView items programmatically when it appears.

I could successfully animate using XML animation file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recycler.adapter = MyAdapter()
        recycler.layoutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_animation_from_right)
        //recycler.itemAnimator = SimpleItemAnimator()
        recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        recycler.scheduleLayoutAnimation()

    }

}
```

This solution is working perfectly fine, but I need to set animation using class extending DefaultItemAnimator.

For this purpose, I have created SimpleItemAnimator class and override its animateApperance method:

```
public class SimpleItemAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {

        @Override
        public boolean animateAppearance(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @Nullable ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
            Log.d("AnimationTag", "animateApperance");
            final MyAdapter.SampleViewHolder holder = (MyAdapter.SampleViewHolder) viewHolder;
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.mTextView, View.TRANSLATION_X, 0, holder.mTextView.getWidth() / 2);
            animator.setDuration(2000);
            animator.start();
            return super.animateAdd(viewHolder);
        }

    }
```

Then I set it to RecyclerView:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recycler.adapter = MyAdapter()
        // recycler.layoutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_animation_from_right)
        recycler.itemAnimator = SimpleItemAnimator()
        recycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        recycler.scheduleLayoutAnimation()

    }

}
```

In result items are not animated and in logs I can not find "animateApperance" which means this method is not being called.

**My question: how to animate RecyclerView items programmatically using DefaultItemAnimator?**

By the way this is code of MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.SampleViewHolder> {

    static class SampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public SampleViewHolder(TextView textView) {
            super(textView);
            mTextView = textView;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        return new SampleViewHolder(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SampleViewHolder sampleViewHolder, int i) {
        sampleViewHolder.mTextView.setText("item "+i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Comment: this is helpful step-by-step guide: https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213

Comment: @Farrokh, thank you for your suggestion. But this link contains animation using XML animation file which is not OK for me. I need to use DefaultItemAnimator class.

Comment: have you tried returning true instead of super.animateAdd(viewHolder);?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones, yes I tried to return true and false, but there is no effect on it